# What is the name of the ancient red dragon that lives near Darkmoon Vale?

Tags: product-identification, lore, golarion

As it is now the third time I've forgotten the name of this dragon and again I'm not sure in which book it is in, I'm going to ask here.

Near the Darkmoon Vale (thus north of Andoran in the mountains, I think the Five Kings summit?) is an ancient red dragon that lives there and who has wyverns as underlings.

I think Olfden is where a bronze dragon lives who is deeply afraid of him.

What is the name of this red dragon and what book is it in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

His name is **Daralathyxl**, and he's described in [*Dragons Revisited*](http://rpggeek.com/rpgitem/54750/dragons-revisited) (2009).

See the [wiki](http://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Daralathyxl) for more information on him.